# Using absolute positioning for drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I am using Jquery to toggle a dropdown area which will hold user selections. I am giving the dropdown "#share-collection-dropdown" div an absolute position. It's parent element 
"#share-collection" has relative positioning, so everything should be working fine. Yet, when you click the dropdown and the "#share-collection-dropdown" div appears, it overflows. I thought that an absolutely positioned element did not affect the flow of the page. What could I be doing wrong?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/DGXk9/

HTML:

```
<div id="share-collection">
    <div id="share-collection-left">
        <a> Choose Collection </a>
    </div>
    <div id="share-collection-right">
        <img src="assets/down_arrow_icon.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="share-collection-dropdown">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#share-collection {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    height: 28px;
    width: 120px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#share-collection-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 29px;
    left: -1px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 140px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look your code in the element `#share-something` at the line where you say `overflow: auto;`. This property defines how your content will be displayed when it exceeds the limits that you defined. Letting the option as `auto` your content will be clipped and a scrolling bar will be added every time that you have this issue.

These are the other possibilities for the property overflow:

- auto
- no-display
- no-content
- visible
- scroll
- hidden

To solve your problem you could use `overflow: visible;` where the content will not be clipped.

You can get more information about this property [here](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/overflow).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On `#share-something` change `overflow: auto;` to `overflow: visible;`